# fill html form using python 3.4

Tags: python, html

I am trying to fill in a html form using python code, the idea is that an agent sends data to the html webpage. After that another python script collects the data (cgi is used). I tried quite some options but I am not able to change the value of the form named 'os' using the agent script. When I fill in the form by hand everything works well and the collector takes over.

If more information is needed i happely provide it.

I hope someone can help me.

Agent script:

```
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1/PythonApp/website.html'
data =  {'os':'test12345'}
session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(url, data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
```

HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>Text</head>
    <body>
        <form action="postmethod.py" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="os" value="abc">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Collector  (postmethod.py):

```
import cgi

# print header
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

print("<h2>Arguments</h2>")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
arg1 = str(form.getvalue('os'))
miauw = ("os: " +arg1+"<br>")
print(miauw)
```

Comment: 1) What is the status code of server's response? 2) Are you sure that data from `requests` session could be parsed by `cgi`? Do you try to save input values somewhere on page by sending your `POST` or just to input some characters into that field?

Comment: @Andersson 1) It returns a long HTML code stating '405 Method Not Allowed you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used. 2) Before processing it with cgi it would have to change the value in the html file if I understand it right, which doesnt work either. Im trying to save the input values, they are supposed to be used in another script that collects them from the html/cgi script

Comment: 1) That means that you can't use `POST` request to send data to specified `URL`... 2) You should look towards `selenium` library. I think this is exactly what you need both to make changes on `HTML` page and scrape data from it

Comment: @Andersson Sorry, Im not very experienced with python and especially requests. Selenium seems to however the idea is that the user doesn't know the data is being send. (its to monitor cpu/ram usage) From what i read Selenium has no 'clean' way of processing the data without the opening of a browser. (btw i really appreciate the time/effort you put to help me!)

Comment: Yes. `selenium` works with common browsers, e.g. `Firefox`, `Chrome` or headless browsers ('PhantomJS'). If you don't know how to use `requests` and how to make proper `HTTP` request to server, you can try to: open your browser -> get to target page -> F12 (to open developer's console) -> Network -> send data to input field -> check developer's console for `HTTP` requests that was sent. After this you'll be able to create exact `HTTP` request that server intend to receive from user